# New Install, Win 8.1 Access over 2 TB

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, raid, uefi

new install, Z87 pro MB, Win 8.1 64 bit, UEFI based.

I have 2 TB drives, configured in a RAID 1+0 config, so end result is approx 4TB useable, and windows shows this.  The problem is that while I can create partitions in the first 2 TB, I can't do ANYTHING with the 2nd unallocated 2 TB.  I believe this has something to do with MBR vs GPT partitioning.  The question is, how do I configure windows to use GPT partitioning.  I don't recall it asking me.. I did load the RAID driver when installing windows.  Is there another driver that I should have loaded as well?

Thanks

Comment: You can't have UEFI and boot to MBR partition if you using a MBR partition your actually booting under legacy mode.  In order for Windows to create a GPT partition the installation media has to be booted in EFI mode and supplied the required drivers.  The simplest fix is to configure the boot order to always load in EFI mode and boot to your installation disk first

Comment: I booted from the Windows 8.1 installation media.  You're saying that the boot has to be in UEFI?  How do I specify this?

Comment: In your UEFI bios.  If the disk does not have the EFI driver it might have defaulted to legacy and/or configured to boot to league first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.. thanks everyone.  My EUFI has a parameter called CSM - Compatibility Support Mode I believe.  I have to set it to EUFI BEFORE formatting the disk, then I can do the install.

Thanks